# How to fix Process finished with exit code -805306369 (0xCFFFFFFF)

Tags: pygame, pycharm, exit-code

I've been getting a weird bug were my game crashes randomly with exit code -805306369 (0xCFFFFFFF) in PyCharm

and I think the error is somewhere in my while loop but idk where

While loop:

```
while True:
    clock.tick(FPS)
    # Start screen
    if Starting_screen is True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                exit()
        screen.fill((101, 67, 33))
        screen.blit(Start_game_box, Start_game_box_rect)
        screen.blit(Play_game_text, Play_game_text_rect)
        screen.blit(Game_name_text, Game_name_text_rect)
        screen.blit(Pepsi_credits_text, Pepsi_credits_text_rect)
        screen.blit(Brew_credits_text, Brew_credits_text_rect)
        screen.blit(Q_credits_text, Q_credits_text_rect)
        screen.blit(mouse, mouse_rect)

        mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
            mx, my = mouse_pos
            mouse_rect.x = mx
            mouse_rect.y = my

        mouse_pressed = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
        if (mouse_pressed[0]) and mouse_rect.colliderect(Start_game_box_rect):
            Main_tycoon_screen = True
            Play_game_text_rect.x = 9999
            Game_name_text_rect.x = 9999
            Start_game_box_rect.x = 9999
            print(Main_tycoon_screen)
            Starting_screen = False
            print(Starting_screen)

        pygame.display.update()

    if Main_tycoon_screen is True:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                exit()

        screen.fill((101, 67, 33))
        screen.blit(dropper1, (100, 400))
        screen.blit(conveyor1, (100, 450))
        screen.blit(dropper1_block, dropperblock1_rect)
        screen.blit(sell_block1, sell_block1_rect)
        screen.blit(Buy_block1, Buy_block1_rect)
        screen.blit(Buy1_cost_text, Buy1_cost_text_rect)

        # functions
        spawn_dropper2()
        spawn_dropper3()
        spawn_dropper4()
        spawn_dropper5()
        spawn_dropper6()
        spawn_dropper7()
        spawn_dropper8()
        spawn_dropper9()
        spawn_dropper10()
        spawn_dropper11()
        spawn_dropper_rainbow()
        spawn_conveyor2()
        setting_stuff()

        dropperblock1_rect.x += 2

        mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        if pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
            mx, my = mouse_pos
            mouse_rect.x = mx
            mouse_rect.y = my
            screen.blit(mouse, mouse_rect)
        # sell block collisions
        if dropperblock12_rect.colliderect(sell_block1_rect):
            monet += 500
            dropperblock12_rect.x = 70
            print(monet)

        if dropperblock11_rect.colliderect(sell_block1_rect):
            monet += 100
            dropperblock11_rect.x = 560
            print(monet)

        if dropperblock10_rect.colliderect(sell_block1_rect):
            monet += 70
            dropperblock10_rect.x = 460
            print(monet)

        if dropperblock9_rect.colliderect(sell_block1_rect):
            monet += 50
            dropperblock9_rect.x = 360
            print(monet)

        if dropperblock8_rect.colliderect(sell_block1_rect):
            monet += 30
            dropperblock8_rect.x = 260
            print(monet)

        if dropperblock7_rect.colliderect(sell_block1_rect):
            monet += 20
            dropperblock7_rect.x = 160
            print(monet)

        if dropperblock6_rect.colliderect(sell_block1_rect):
            monet += 15
            dropperblock6_rect.x = 600
            print(monet)

        if dropperblock5_rect.colliderect(sell_block1_rect):
            monet += 15
            dropperblock5_rect.x = 500
            print(monet)

        if dropperblock4_rect.colliderect(sell_block1_rect):
            monet += 10
            dropperblock4_rect.x = 400
            print(monet)

        if dropperblock3_rect.colliderect(sell_block1_rect):
            monet += 8
            dropperblock3_rect.x = 300
            print(monet)

        if dropperblock2_rect.colliderect(sell_block1_rect):
            monet += 6
            dropperblock2_rect.x = 200
            print(monet)

        if dropperblock1_rect.colliderect(sell_block1_rect):
            monet += 5
            dropperblock1_rect.x = 100
            print(monet)

        # Buy block collisions
        mouse_pressed = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
        if (mouse_pressed[0]) and mouse_rect.colliderect(Buy_block1_rect) and monet >= 10:
            monet -= 10
            Buy_block1_rect.x = 999
            Buy_block1_rect.y = 999
            Spawn_dropper2 = True
            print(monet)
            pygame.mixer.Sound.play(Buying_dropper_sound)

        if (mouse_pressed[0]) and mouse_rect.colliderect(Buy_block2_rect) and monet >= 30:
            monet -= 30
            Buy_block2_rect.x = 999
            Buy_block2_rect.y = 999
            Buy2_cost_text_rect.x = 999
            Spawn_dropper3 = True
            print(monet)
            pygame.mixer.Sound.play(Buying_dropper_sound)

        if (mouse_pressed[0]) and mouse_rect.colliderect(Buy_block3_rect) and monet >= 100:
            monet -= 100
            Buy_block3_rect.x = 999
            Buy_block3_rect.y = 999
            Buy3_cost_text_rect.x = 999
            Spawn_dropper4 = True
            print(monet)
            pygame.mixer.Sound.play(Buying_dropper_sound)

        if (mouse_pressed[0]) and mouse_rect.colliderect(Buy_block4_rect) and monet >= 200:
            monet -= 200
            Buy_block4_rect.x = 999
            Buy_block4_rect.y = 999
            Buy4_cost_text_rect.x = 999
            Spawn_dropper5 = True
            print(monet)
            pygame.mixer.Sound.play(Buying_dropper_sound)

        if (mouse_pressed[0]) and mouse_rect.colliderect(Buy_block5_rect) and monet >= 500:
            monet -= 500
            Buy_block5_rect.x = 999
            Buy_block5_rect.y = 999
            Buy5_cost_text_rect.x = 999
            Spawn_dropper6 = True
            print(monet)
            pygame.mixer.Sound.play(Buying_dropper_sound)

        if (mouse_pressed[0]) and mouse_rect.colliderect(Buy_block6_rect) and monet >= 1000:
            monet -= 1000
            Buy_block6_rect.x = 999
            Buy_block6_rect.y = 999
            Buy6_cost_text_rect.x = 999
            Spawn_dropper7 = True
            print(monet)
            pygame.mixer.Sound.play(Buying_dropper_sound)

        if (mouse_pressed[0]) and mouse_rect.colliderect(Buy_block7_rect) and monet >= 1500:
            monet -= 1500
            Buy_block7_rect.x = 999
            Buy_block7_rect.y = 999
            Buy7_cost_text_rect.x = 999
            Spawn_dropper8 = True
            print(monet)
            pygame.mixer.Sound.play(Buying_dropper_sound)

        if (mouse_pressed[0]) and mouse_rect.colliderect(Buy_block8_rect) and monet >= 2000:
            monet -= 2000
            Buy_block8_rect.x = 999
            Buy_block8_rect.y = 999
            Buy8_cost_text_rect.x = 999
            Spawn_dropper9 = True
            print(monet)
            pygame.mixer.Sound.play(Buying_dropper_sound)

        if (mouse_pressed[0]) and mouse_rect.colliderect(Buy_block9_rect) and monet >= 3000:
            monet -= 3000
            Buy_block9_rect.x = 999
            Buy_block9_rect.y = 999
            Buy9_cost_text_rect.x = 999
            Spawn_dropper10 = True
            print(monet)
            pygame.mixer.Sound.play(Buying_dropper_sound)

        if (mouse_pressed[0]) and mouse_rect.colliderect(Buy_block10_rect) and monet >= 4000:
            monet -= 4000
            Buy_block10_rect.x = 999
            Buy_block10_rect.y = 999
            Buy10_cost_text_rect.x = 999
            Spawn_dropper11 = True
            print(monet)
            pygame.mixer.Sound.play(Buying_dropper_sound)

        if (mouse_pressed[0]) and mouse_rect.colliderect(Buy_block11_rect) and monet >= 5000:
            monet -= 5000
            Buy_block11_rect.x = 999
            Buy_block11_rect.y = 999
            Buy11_cost_text_rect.x = 999
            Spawn_dropper12 = True
            print(monet)
            pygame.mixer.Sound.play(Buying_dropper_sound)

        if (mouse_pressed[0]) and mouse_rect.colliderect(Buy_conveyor2_block_rect) and monet >= 10000:
            monet -= 10000
            Buy_conveyor2_block_rect.x = 999
            Buy_conveyor2_text_rect.x = 999
            Spawn_conveyor2 = True
            print(monet)
            pygame.mixer.Sound.play(Buying_dropper_sound)

        draw_monet_counter(f"monet: {monet}", "white", 60, 600, 50)

        pygame.display.update()
```

and here are the funcitons

```
Spawn_conveyor2 = False

Spawn_dropper2 = False
Spawn_dropper3 = False
Spawn_dropper4 = False
Spawn_dropper5 = False
Spawn_dropper6 = False
Spawn_dropper7 = False
Spawn_dropper8 = False
Spawn_dropper9 = False
Spawn_dropper10 = False
Spawn_dropper11 = False
Spawn_dropper12 = False

Spawn_pho_dropper1 = False


def spawn_conveyor2():
    if Spawn_conveyor2 is True:
        screen.blit(conveyor2, (100, 200))
        Buy_conveyor2_block_rect.x = 999
        Buy_conveyor2_text_rect.x = 9999
        Buy_pho1_rect.x = 110
        screen.blit(Buy_pho1, Buy_pho1_rect)


def spawn_dropper2():
    if Spawn_dropper2 is True:
        Buy_block1_rect.x = 2400
        screen.blit(Buy2_cost_text, Buy2_cost_text_rect)
        screen.blit(dropper2, (200, 390))
        screen.blit(dropper2_block, dropperblock2_rect)
        Buy_block2_rect.x = 300
        screen.blit(Buy_block2, Buy_block2_rect)
        dropperblock2_rect.x += 2
        Buy1_cost_text_rect.x = 999


def spawn_dropper3():
    if Spawn_dropper3 is True:
        screen.blit(dropper3, (300, 390))
        screen.blit(dropper3_block, dropperblock3_rect)
        dropperblock3_rect.x += 2
        Buy_block3_rect.x = 400
        screen.blit(Buy_block3, Buy_block3_rect)
        screen.blit(Buy3_cost_text, Buy3_cost_text_rect)


def spawn_dropper4():
    if Spawn_dropper4 is True:
        screen.blit(dropper4, (400, 390))
        screen.blit(dropper4_block, dropperblock4_rect)
        dropperblock4_rect.x += 2
        Buy_block4_rect.x = 500
        screen.blit(Buy_block4, Buy_block4_rect)
        screen.blit(Buy4_cost_text, Buy4_cost_text_rect)


def spawn_dropper5():
    if Spawn_dropper5 is True:
        screen.blit(dropper5, (500, 390))
        screen.blit(dropper5_block, dropperblock5_rect)
        dropperblock5_rect.x += 2
        Buy_block5_rect.x = 600
        screen.blit(Buy_block5, Buy_block5_rect)
        screen.blit(Buy5_cost_text, Buy5_cost_text_rect)


def spawn_dropper6():
    if Spawn_dropper6 is True:
        screen.blit(dropper6, (600, 390))
        screen.blit(dropper6_block, dropperblock6_rect)
        dropperblock6_rect.x += 1
        Buy_block6_rect.x = 160
        screen.blit(Buy_block6, Buy_block6_rect)
        screen.blit(Buy6_cost_text, Buy6_cost_text_rect)


def spawn_dropper7():
    if Spawn_dropper7 is True:
        screen.blit(dropper7, (160, 500))
        screen.blit(dropper7_block, dropperblock7_rect)
        dropperblock7_rect.x += 2
        Buy_block7_rect.x = 260
        screen.blit(Buy_block7, Buy_block7_rect)
        screen.blit(Buy7_cost_text, Buy7_cost_text_rect)


def spawn_dropper8():
    if Spawn_dropper8 is True:
        screen.blit(dropper8, (260, 500))
        screen.blit(dropper8_block, dropperblock8_rect)
        dropperblock8_rect.x += 2
        Buy_block8_rect.x = 360
        screen.blit(Buy_block8, Buy_block8_rect)
        screen.blit(Buy8_cost_text, Buy8_cost_text_rect)
        screen.blit(Buy_conveyor2_text, Buy_conveyor2_text_rect)
        screen.blit(Buy_conveyor2_block, Buy_conveyor2_block_rect)


def spawn_dropper9():
    if Spawn_dropper9 is True:
        screen.blit(dropper9, (360, 500))
        screen.blit(dropper9_block, dropperblock9_rect)
        dropperblock9_rect.x += 2
        Buy_block9_rect.x = 460
        screen.blit(Buy_block9, Buy_block9_rect)
        screen.blit(Buy9_cost_text, Buy9_cost_text_rect)


def spawn_dropper10():
    if Spawn_dropper10 is True:
        screen.blit(dropper10, (460, 500))
        screen.blit(dropper10_block, dropperblock10_rect)
        dropperblock10_rect.x += 2
        Buy_block10_rect.x = 560
        screen.blit(Buy_block10, Buy_block10_rect)
        screen.blit(Buy10_cost_text, Buy10_cost_text_rect)


def spawn_dropper11():
    if Spawn_dropper11 is True:
        screen.blit(dropper11, (560, 500))
        screen.blit(dropper11_block, dropperblock11_rect)
        dropperblock11_rect.x += 2
        Buy_block11_rect.x = 40
        screen.blit(Buy_block11, Buy_block11_rect)
        screen.blit(Buy11_cost_text, Buy11_cost_text_rect)


def spawn_dropper_rainbow():
    if Spawn_dropper12 is True:
        screen.blit(dropper12, (40, 450))
        screen.blit(Rainbow_block_red, (15, 450))
        screen.blit(Rainbow_block_blue, (35, 450))
        screen.blit(Rainbow_block_yellow, (50, 450))
        screen.blit(Rainbow_block_purple, (65, 450))
        screen.blit(Rainbow_block_green, (80, 450))
        screen.blit(dropper12_block, dropperblock12_rect)
        dropperblock12_rect.x += 2

Starting_screen = True
Main_tycoon_screen = False
Setting_On = False
Setting_Off = True
Music = True

def setting_stuff():
    global Setting_On, Setting_Off, Music, Tycoon_music1, Starting_screen_music, mouse_pressed

    screen.blit(Setting_button, Setting_button_rect)
    screen.blit(setting_button_icon, setting_button_icon_rect)

    mouse_pressed = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    if (mouse_pressed[0]) and mouse_rect.colliderect(Setting_button_rect):
        Setting_Off = False
        Setting_On = True

    if Setting_On is True:
        Setting_Background_rect.x = 200
        exit_setting_button_rect.x = 470
        screen.blit(Setting_Background, Setting_Background_rect)
        screen.blit(exit_setting_button, exit_setting_button_rect)

        setting_button_icon_rect.x = 999
        Setting_button_rect.x = 999

        pause_music_block_rect.x = 250
        pause_music_text_rect.x = 260
        screen.blit(pause_music_block, pause_music_block_rect)
        screen.blit(pause_music_text, pause_music_text_rect)

        unpause_music_block_rect.x = 250
        unpause_music_text_rect.x = 260
        screen.blit(unpause_music_block, unpause_music_block_rect)
        screen.blit(unpause_music_text, unpause_music_text_rect)

    if (mouse_pressed[0]) and mouse_rect.colliderect(exit_setting_button_rect):
        Setting_On = False
        Setting_Off = True

    if (mouse_pressed[0]) and mouse_rect.colliderect(pause_music_block_rect):
        Music = False

    if (mouse_pressed[0]) and mouse_rect.colliderect(unpause_music_block_rect):
        Music = True

    if Music is False:
        pygame.mixer.music.pause()

    if Music is True:
        pygame.mixer.music.unpause()

    if Setting_Off is True:
        pause_music_block_rect. x = 999
        pause_music_text_rect.x = 999
        unpause_music_block_rect.x = 999
        unpause_music_text_rect.x = 999
        Setting_Background_rect.x = 999
        exit_setting_button_rect.x = 999
        setting_button_icon_rect.x = 50
        Setting_button_rect.x = 50
```

the error happens when i hit a button in the game sometimes it happens and sometimes not and i dont know how to fix it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pygame not working with pycharm community edition (not responding)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63166767/pygame-not-working-with-pycharm-community-edition-not-responding)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit the question it should have no more code than the minimum necessary to reproduce the problem by copy-pasting, a [*"Minimal, Reproducible, Example."*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Also, see [these questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=exit%20code%20%22-805306369%22%20%5bpython%5d).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely that somehow both your variables `Starting_screen` and `Main_tycoon_screen` are becoming `False`.  With both of these false, you are no longer handling the window event queue.  The operating system notices your application is no longer processing events (i.e. "Not Responding"), and takes the action of terminating it.  This results in the 0xCFFFFFFF code.

I suggest you modify your program to process the window events in a single place, and *always* process the event queue.

```
START_SCREEN = 1
GAME_SCREEN  = 2
current_screen = START_SCREEN

while True:
    # Handle events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exit()

    mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    mouse_pressed = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

    clock.tick(FPS)

    if ( current_screen == START_SCREEN ):
        pass
        # TODO paint start screen
        # TODO handle start screen events
    elif ( current_screen == GAME_SCREEN ):
        pass
        # TODO paint game screen
        # TODO handle game screen events
```

This framework allows you to switch between the "state" of the application by setting the `current_screen` variable.  But the key point is that is *always* handling the event queue, no matter what the `current_screen`.